# Deployment of self-signed msi

Tags: deployment, windows-installer, self-signed

I just created an msi installer for an application that i will distribute from my website. I digitally signed the msi using openSSL. Now my question is: how do I package the msi so that it can be installed on users' computers? Should I send the user the certificate I created by email so he can run the msi? Which is the preferred procedure for doing things in this case?

Comment: If your MSI is signed, just send it to the customers. If the cert is registered with a cert provider it will be checked when they install it. Don't send anyone your certificate!  You don't want them using it to sign code and make it look like it came from you.

Comment: But the MSI is self-signed using openSSL, I haven't paid for anything and wouldn't pay because I'm giving this application for free on my website. I'm not sure if just sending the self-signed msi will work!

Comment: Try it, but why bother signing it? The whole point of signing is 3rd party verification - the customer doesn't trust you - the verification is at the certificate provider. It doesn't mean anything to say "i'm trustworthy - I've signed it with my own homemade certificate". If you're expecting the customer install to treat you as trusted, well it won't happen.

Comment: Then I guess the only solution for people to download my app is to pay for a digital certificate which I find laughably expensive! Or give away the source code which I don't want for this particular application... hmmm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on what you're trying to accomplish by signing the MSI. If you just want to allow it to install, you're already done; Windows doesn't disallow the installation of unsigned MSI files. If you're trying to get a green UAC prompt, then the signing certificate needs to be verifiable. This can be done by purchasing the certificate appropriately, or by installing a self-signed certificate or its root on each target machine. (The latter is common within enterprises for items the enterprise itself has signed.)

If you're trying to actually ensure safety, however, you quickly encounter a chicken-and-egg problem. A file signed with a certificate issued to X is supposed to confirm the bits came from X, and allow a user to decide if X is trustworthy. Part of this requires knowing nobody else could have used a certificate claiming to have been issued to X. If you are using a self-signed certificate, or one issued by a self-signed root, there is no built-in chain of identity validation. (It's no longer Morgan's child's roommate; instead it's just someone's roommate.)

How do you safely get the identifying information, such as the root certificate, to the user? How can they be sure it wasn't a malicious version that trusts the fake X? (How do you introduce Morgan when nobody knows him, without getting some fellow Murphy who just calls himself Morgan?) Outside of the enterprise scenario I alluded to above, or ways that start with a paid certificate, I'm not aware of any good ways.

Comment: Yes, I've been thinking a lot about it and I agree there's no other way than to pay for it. Now why is that i see such a big fluctuation in prices among the different providers? Which would be the best way to go in your experience? Thanks all for your comments!

Comment: Prices may reflect the care the certificate authority takes in verifying your identity. Or just what the market bears. I've never bought a certificate myself, so can only recommend finding a vendor supporting SHA-2 authenticode code-signing certificates.

Comment: Ok, I've done some research and Comodo seems to have the best offer... I just hope their certificate is as reliable as Symantec's which is the priciest (ridiculously expensive, BTW)